# ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" postgresql query with params

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jpa

I have a postgres query with params, in my Java code, am using stringBuilder to build the query and then createNativeQuery to create query and populating the params. However if I run the query in my gui, it gives me the result which is expected, but gives error when executing via code. I'm a newbie on postgres and have seen some questions with the nearly same problems that I need to cast the params in the query, but I do have IN param inside my query which is list, I've tried some solutions but didn't worked.

**I' am getting error as :->**
"error": "Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: **ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 249**

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(" SELECT comments.comment, mapping.user_id, 
        mapping.comment_id, mapping.comment_state, 
        mapping.created_at  FROM comments ").append(" comment 
        JOIN ").
        append(" user_comment_mapping  mapping ON 
        mapping.comment_id = comment.id WHERE 
        mapping.user_id IN ? AND mapping.comment_state = ? 
        ");

        final Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sb.toString());
        query.setParameter("1", userIds);
        query.setParameter("2", 
        2);

        List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to do this `mapping.user_id IN (?) AND mapping.comment_state = ?`?

Comment: As an aside, do you have any particular reason for using StringBuilder rather than just String with concatenation? There aren't any variables here, so the string concatenation would just happen at compile time, giving you code which is more efficient and easier to read.

Comment: @JonSkeet no, there was no reason to use Sb in particular.

Comment: @RJB yeah, tried that, but still getting **Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use**

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are mixing between parameter holder and name so.

If you want to use holder :

```
mapping.user_id IN ? AND mapping.comment_state = ?
```

then

```
query.setParameter(1, userIds);
query.setParameter(2, 2);
```

If you want to use names :

```
mapping.user_id IN :ids AND mapping.comment_state = :stat


query.setParameter("ids", userIds);
query.setParameter("stat", 2);
```

Comment: or in other words, do not quote `1` and `2`

Comment: @ScaryWombat  do you mean like stated  query.setParameter(1, userIds);
query.setParameter(2, 2); ?

Comment: Yes, only quote for named paramaters

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tried that, but now am getting **Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use**

Comment: Yeah, you may want to search how to create queries with `IN`